# When can vectors of one basis be expressed as linear combination of vectors of another basis with unitary matrix coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If I have two  normalized basis $\{v\}$ and $\{w\}$ for the same hilbert space of dimension $n$ ( not necessarily orthogonal ), then when can we write the following
$$v_i=\sum c_{ij}w_j.....(1)$$
such that $c_{ij}$ denotes the $ij^{\text{th}}$ entry of a unitary matrix. I know that if both of the basis $\{v\}$ and $\{w\}$ are orthonormal  then $(1)$ holds true . Are there any other cases where $(1)$ holds true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your question is asking when a unitary matrix can map one basis to a second basis.

First, of all, a matrix is unitary if and only if it preserves inner products, so if $\{v\}$ is orthonormal and (1) holds so is $\{w\}$.  Thus, your claim isn't quite right.  However, if both $\{v\}$ and $\{w\}$ are orthonormal bases, then the matrix that sends each $v_i$ to $w_i$ is unitary.

In general, (1) holds when the [Gram matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) for $\{v\}$ and $\{w\}$ are similar by a permutation matrix.  In other words, when there exists a permutation $\pi$ such that $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle = \langle w_{\pi(i)}, w_{\pi(j)}\rangle$ for all $i, j$.  In this case, the unitary matrix is the one that maps each $v_i$ to $w_{\pi(i)}$.

Comment: my question asks when in what input output basis representation of an identity operator is unitary. Also I edited/corrected the mistake you pointed out.

Comment: If you want to require that $v_i$ maps to $w_i$ then just add the additional restriction that $\pi$ is the identity above.  As written, it's equivalent to what I wrote though.